# LNK2019 constructor/destructor using C++ Dll

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll, wrapper

I am developping a C++ DLL with a C wrapper in order to use it in Python and C#. So I create on Visual Studio a project (DLL) to develop and compile it. No problem here. I even can use my DLL on Python without trouble.

But, on Visual, I want to create another project in the same solution as the DLL to test the DLL too.

So I created the second project (Win32 Windows Application), added the *.h* to the header files, added the link to the *.lib* file I added in the folder of the test project, but when I try to compile it, I have errors about LNK2019, beginning with the constructor:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl Projet::Projet(void)" (??Projet@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
```

**DLL = Projet / Test = Projet_Test**

**Projet.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Projet_inc.h"

class Projet
{
public:
    Projet();
    ~Projet();

    int multiply(int arg1, int arg2);
    int result;
};
```

**Projet_inc.h**

```
#ifdef PROJET_EXPORTS
#  define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#define CALLCONV_API __stdcall

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" // C wrapper
{
#endif

    typedef struct Projet Projet; // make the class opaque to the wrapper

    EXPORT Projet* CALLCONV_API cCreateObject(void);
    EXPORT int CALLCONV_API cMultiply(Projet* pDLLobject, int arg1, int arg2);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**Projet.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Projet.h"

Projet::Projet() {}
Projet::~Projet() {}

int Projet::multiply(int arg1, int arg2) {
    result = arg1 * arg2;
    return result;
}

Projet* EXPORT CALLCONV_API  cCreateObject(void)
{
    return new Projet();
}

int EXPORT CALLCONV_API  cMultiply(Projet* pDLLtest, int arg1, int arg2)
{
    if (!pDLLtest)
        return 0;
    return pDLLtest->multiply(arg1, arg2);
}
```

**Projet_Test.cpp**

```
// Projet_Test.cpp : définit le point d'entrée pour l'application console.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Projet.h"

int main()
{
    Projet object;
    return 0;
}
```

On Visual, I select the test project as startup project for information. And I look a lot of posts on SO but I didn't find the solution for now. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The symbol referenced in the error message does not match any symbol in your code. Either this code is incomplete, or fake. Either way, fix it by providing a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `__declspec(dllexport)` *all* functions that you want to call directly, not just the C ones.

In your example, you should be able to correctly call the C wrapper functions `cCreateObject` and `cMultiply`, as those were exported correctly, but you will not be able to call the underlying C++ functions like `Projet::Projet()` and `Projet::~Projet()`.

You have two ways of solving this: You can change these functions to inline functions and move their implementation to the header. That way, the client project will no longer invoke the code from the DLL for those functions, but instead just compile the inline definitions directly itself. This is obviously not a sensible approach in general. Alternatively, mark your C++ member functions with `__declspec(dllexport)`, just as you did with the C functions.

Note that Visual Studio has a tendency of breaking the C++ ABI between versions, so you need to make sure that the compiler version you used for compiling the dll is compatible with the one you used for compiling the client application. This is not an issue if both parts are compiled with the same Visual Studio version or if you stick with a plain C interface.

Comment: Thank you, I now define my class `class __declspec(dllexport) Projet` and it is working. I have to send my DLL to my colleague to be sure he can read it in C# now.

Answer (score 1):

First, the error about the missing symbol EpsCndCoreDll seems to be out of context here and you should rather be getting a compile error about redefining struct as a class (class Projet).

Probably you need to use something like:

```
class Projet;
typedef Projet* PProjet;
```

and use PProject as the opaque handle further on.

You also need to export the Projet class like:

```
class EXPORT Projet
```

to be able to instantiate that class by a client or add a factory function that returns a reference.

Comment: Sorry I change the name of some variables for my post and forget `EpsCndCoreDll` which corresponds to `Projet`. Adding`__declspec(dllexport)` in the definition of my class solve the problem ;)

Comment: Using hard coded __declspec(dllexport) will kill optimizations in importing the class by clients. Use the EXPORT macro you created before.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you have added the DLL reference to your DLL.

Comment: *"Adding a DLL reference to a DLL"* does not make any sense in a native application. Native applications use import libraries to resolve symbols.